# What is the "official" tablesorter repository?

Tags: github, tablesorter

I just found the [Mottie/tablesorter repository](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) after implementing the –what I thought to be– [original repository from Chrisitian Back](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter).

The description of Mottie's repo says:

> Github fork of Christian Bach's tablesorter plugin + awesomeness

Now when reading this, three questions come up:

1. Why is this one not marked as fork on github (usually if this is a little hint below the repository name if it's a fork - that's missing on this repo)
2. Is "+ awesomeness" in the repository description something specific (e.g. a JS lib) or is this just some kind of "marketing term" for this repo?
3. What are the major differences between this repository and the original one from Christian Bach?
4. Can I easily migrate to Mottie's repo (as it is [much more vivid according to its Pulse](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/pulse/monthly))? What do I have to watch at when doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the [issue that was opened](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/771):

1. Christian Bach added his GitHub repository on May 20, 2014, whereas my fork was created somewhere around June 2011. So there really isn't a way for me to fork from his repo now. Nothing is missing, except for a few documented changes to the options; but **a lot** has been added.
2. "+ awesomeness" was just added to distinguish this fork from the original; especially because **most of the widgets available for this fork will not work with the original**. I have tried different methods to help distinguish this difference... "+ awesomeness" is just one way. Now the [main document page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) has "unoffical fork" at the top to try to make it more obvious. Eventually, I plan to rename this fork to [Abelt](https://github.com/tablesort/Abelt) (which has lots of breaking changes) to avoid further confusion.
3. I have *some* documented differences on the [summary wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Summary). Sadly, I haven't had the time nor the inclination to update it since version 2.7 (currently we're on v2.18.3). That should at least get you started. Other than that, I feel like the documentation is pretty extensive, so you can always fall back on it if you have questions.

---

4. If you have a basic set up working with the original tablesorter, then there is shouldn't be any major changes needed to just swap out the original with the forked version. With a more complex set up, you might have to tweak a few things. Post some code, I'll try to help. It won't be as bad as you think.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and kind answer – also on github.